# Print a Shiny reactive value on WordR

Tags: r, shiny, docx, officer, wordr

I am looking for some help please to print a reactive value in a Shiny session into a docx with WordR. A very stripped down version of my app is presented below.

The code for the docx template is `` `r reactive({declared_user()})` `` (which is bookended with MS Word’s formatting symbols). I don’t know how to show the format symbols or provide the docx template here on SO but that’s the only applicable code.

I have tried numerous ways of wrapping the `declared_user()` in a reactive context in both the r file and docx but still can’t seem to see either value/user in ‘slt_input’ printing out in rprt_out.docx.

All that prints out is…
*function ()  {     .dependents$register()     if (.invalidated || .running) {         ..stacktraceoff..(self$.updateValue())     }     if (.error) {         stop(.value)     }     if (.visible)          .value     else invisible(.value) }*

```
library(shiny)
library(WordR)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('slt_input', 'name', choices = c("god", 'devil')),
  actionButton("btn_inline", 'inline')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  declared_user <- reactive({
    input$slt_input
  })

  observeEvent(input$btn_inline,{
    renderInlineCode("rprt_tmplt.docx", "rprt_out.docx")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I think 2 things complicated the issue:

- `renderInlineCode` extracts the R code from the .docx template and uses `eval` to evaluate the code. Somehow, it couldn't use the correct environment for the evaluation. Therefore I slightly changed the code so that you can pass the environment as an argument to the function.
- it still doesn't work to evaluate shiny code. Therefore, I generated a normal variable out of the reactive directly before the docx rendering and use this in the template

```
library(shiny)
library(WordR)
library(officer)
library(dplyr)

renderInlineCode_2 <- function (docxIn, docxOut, eval_envir = parent.frame(), debug = F) 
{
  if (debug) {
    browser()
  }
  doc <- officer::read_docx(docxIn)
  smm <- officer::docx_summary(doc)
  styles <- officer::styles_info(doc)
  regx <- "^[ ]*`r[ ](.*)`$"
  smm$expr <- ifelse(grepl(regx, smm$text), sub(regx, "\\1", 
                                                smm$text), NA)
  smm$values <- sapply(smm$expr, FUN = function(x) {
    eval(parse(text = x), envir = eval_envir)
  })
  smm <- smm[!is.na(smm$expr), , drop = F]
  i <- 3
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(smm))) {
    stylei <- switch(ifelse(is.na(smm$style_name[i]), "a", 
                            "b"), a = NULL, b = styles$style_name[styles$style_id == 
                                                                    paste0(styles$style_id[styles$style_name == smm$style_name[i] & 
                                                                                             styles$style_type == "paragraph"], "Char")])
    doc <- officer::cursor_reach(doc, keyword = paste0("\\Q", 
                                                       smm$text[i], "\\E")) %>% officer::body_remove() %>% 
      officer::cursor_backward() %>% officer::slip_in_text(smm$values[i], 
                                                           pos = "after", style = stylei)
  }
  print(doc, target = docxOut)
  return(docxOut)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput('slt_input', 'name', choices = c("god", 'devil')),
  actionButton("btn_inline", 'inline')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  declared_user <- reactive({
    input$slt_input
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_inline,{
    eval_user <- declared_user()
    renderInlineCode_2("rprt_tmplt.docx", "rprt_out.docx")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the template, use:

```
`r eval_user`
```

---

**Edit**

When thinking a bit more about it, I think in the original `renderInlineCode` function the `parent.frame()` of `eval` is `renderInlineCode`. Obviously, there the required objects are not included but in its `parent.frame()`. So you have to relay on R's scoping which doesn't work correctly here with shiny. I'm happy to get some more thorough explanations.

Comment: Thanks. And apologies for the tardy response. The most important aspect of your solution was directing me more towards the officer package which I now realize offers much more server side control, especially with 'piping' and string manipulation with the reactives. Your solution addresses the question so I will accept it as the preferred